# How to Save Input Data to Database using a Modal in Laravel 7

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I'm starting a new investment project in Laravel and i'm trying to save new input data from my blade file using a modal however for some reason it's not saving to my sql database. There's no error whatsoever and here are what I've got:

Database schema is:

```
Schema::create('money_trades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->string('mt_number');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('bank');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('mt_first_name');
        $table->string('mt_last_name');
        $table->string('mt_password');
        $table->string('mt_account');
        $table->string('mt_deposit');
        $table->string('mt_leverage');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Model is MoneyTrade.php

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

MoneyTradeController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'bank' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        'mt_first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mt_account' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_deposit' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_leverage' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],

    ]);

    $moneyTrade = new MoneyTrade();

    $moneyTrade->mt_number = uniqid('MTNumber-');

    $moneyTrade->bank = $request->input('bank');
    $moneyTrade->email = $request->input('email');
    $moneyTrade->mt_first_name = $request->input('mt_first_name');
    $moneyTrade->mt_last_name = $request->input('mt_last_name');
    $moneyTrade->mt_password = $request->input('mt_password');
    $moneyTrade->mt_account = $request->input('mt_account');
    $moneyTrade->mt_deposit = $request->input('mt_deposit');
    $moneyTrade->mt_leverage = $request->input('mt_leverage');

    $moneyTrade->user_id = auth()->id();

    $moneyTrade->save();


    return redirect()->route('home')->withMessage('MoneyTrade Account Created');

}
```

I have a route in web.php

```
Route::resource('moneytrade', 'MoneyTradeController')->middleware('auth');
```

And my blade file is

```
                        <!-- Moneytrade Register Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                          <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Open an Account</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                    <form action="{{route('moneytrade.store')}}" method="post">
                                        @csrf

                                        <h3><b>Personal Details</b></h3>
                                        <p><center> To open an account, please fill out the following fields:</center></p>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="bank" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Bank') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="bank" type="text" class="form-control @error('bank') is-invalid @enderror" name="bank" value="MoneyTrade Bank" required autocomplete="current-bank" readonly>

                                                @error('bank')
                                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                                @error('email')
                                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="mt_first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="mt_first_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('mt_first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="mt_first_name" value="{{ old('mt_first_name') }}" placeholder="First name of the account owner" required autocomplete="mt_first_name" autofocus>

                                                @error('mt_first_name')
                                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="mt_last_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="mt_last_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('mt_last_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="mt_last_name" value="{{ old('mt_last_name') }}" placeholder="Last name of the account owner" required autocomplete="mt_last_name" autofocus>

                                                @error('mt_last_name')
                                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="mt_password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="mt_password" type="password" class="form-control @error('mt_password') is-invalid @enderror" name="mt_password" placeholder="Minimum of 8 characters" required autocomplete="new-mt_password">

                                                @error('mt_password')
                                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="mt_password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="mt_password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Minimum of 8 characters" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Use hedge in investment and trading</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="mt_account" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Account Type') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <select name="mt_account" class="form-control @error('mt_account') is-invalid @enderror">
                                                    <option value="forex-php">forex-php</option>
                                                    <option value="forex-usd">forex-usd</option>
                                                </select>
                                                @error('mt_account')
                                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="mt_deposit" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Deposit') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="mt_deposit" type="text" class="form-control @error('mt_deposit') is-invalid @enderror" name="mt_deposit" value="2500" placeholder="Last name of the policy owner" required autocomplete="mt_deposit" autofocus >

                                                @error('mt_deposit')
                                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="mt_leverage" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Leverage') }}</label>

                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <select name="mt_leverage" class="form-control @error('mt_leverage') is-invalid @enderror">
                                                    <option value="l100">100</option>
                                                    <option value="l500">500</option>
                                                    <option value="l1000">1000</option>
                                                </select>
                                                @error('mt_leverage')
                                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                @enderror

                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>I agree with the terms and conditions for opening an account and the data protection policy.</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                       
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is what I get when I try to dd on $request
[image: This is what I get when I try to dd on $request]

Can anyone please help me what's wrong? Is it my route or does the modal have something to do with it or something else? It's my first time to try it in a modal so I'm not really sure since I'm new to Laravel and trying to explore it more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Nothing in your laravel.log?

Comment: No I din't get any error at all. Can I how can I check the laravel.log?

Comment: what happens exactly when you attempt to save? are you sure your store method is called? try dumping $request->all()

Comment: When I try to save it just redirects to home but doesn't save to my database. I have a `<form action="{{route('moneytrade.store')}}" method="post">
                                        @csrf` on my modal. Should I make a new route for it? Because I only made a route `Route::resource('moneytrade', 'MoneyTradeController')->middleware('auth');`.  I updated the post and attached an image whenever I dump $request. Please check. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, would it be easier if I just made it on a normal webpage instead of a modal? I'm not sure if the modal is making it more complicated as i'm just trying it out to explore. Thanks

Comment: the fact that you got the request dumped means your route is good, something is happening in the model creation phase, can you dump the create model after saving

Comment: modal of not shouldn't make any difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223937/discussion-between-rabah-and-jemy).

Comment: when you use `$moneyTrade->save();` it returns a boolean value, you can `dd($moneyTrade->save());` & check if returns true or not. Infact you can use check directly `if($moneyTrade->save()){return redirect()->route('home')->withMessage('MoneyTrade Account Created');}`